# PHP Delete Multiple File Image in folder

Tags: php, image, upload

I have trouble when i want delete Multiple File Image in folder, i can delete the image in folder but just 1 image, other image can't delete in folder although in DB the image is 1 id, this my script

```
if (ISSET($_POST['remove_product'])) {
require("../koneksi.php");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$cari=mysql_query("select * from t_productimage where id_product='$id'");
$dt=mysql_fetch_array($cari);
$gmbr=$dt['image'];
$tmpfile = "../images_product/$gmbr";
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE a.*, b.*, c.* FROM t_product a, t_productsize b, t_productimage c WHERE a.id = '$id' AND b.id_product = '$id' AND c.id_product = '$id'");
if(!$sql){
echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert("delete gambar gagal !");</script>';
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=home.php?p=product'>";
    }else{
            unlink ($tmpfile);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=home.php?p=product'>";
    }
exit();
}
```

thks a lot for responsed

Comment: put `$dt` inside a foreach loop and all deleting code

Comment: thks for respon danial but i'm sorry i don't understand about that, can u tell me with example script T_T ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `mysql` is no longer recommended as it has been deprecated for some time and the code is vulnerable to sql injection, but you could try like this.

Fetch the results and then iterate though using a simple loop and use the returned value to populate an array which can then be used to display a message or redirect as you see fit.

You ought to however look into using `mysqli` or `PDO` in conjunction with `prepared statements`

```
if( isset( $_POST['remove_product'] ) ) {

    require("../koneksi.php");
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $results=array();


    $cari=mysql_query("select * from t_productimage where id_product='$id'");
    if( $cari ){

        while( $dt=mysql_fetch_array( $cari ) ){

            $gmbr = $dt['image'];
            $tmpfile = "../images_product/$gmbr";                   

            $results[ $gmbr ]=@unlink( $tmpfile );
        }

        $result=mysql_query("DELETE 
                                a.*, 
                                b.*, 
                                c.* 
                            FROM 
                                t_product a, 
                                t_productsize b, 
                                t_productimage c 
                            WHERE 
                                a.id = '$id' AND b.id_product = '$id' AND c.id_product = '$id'");

        $results['product-deleted']=$result;
    }

    if( !empty( $results ) ){
        foreach( $results as $key => $status ){
            printf('<div>%s -> %s</div>', $key, $status ? 'deleted' : 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Mr Ram, it's worked,

yes ram,i am currently studying mysqli, i says thanks again for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Using following function, you can delete multiple images or images in multi level folder structure like given example:

`**folders** 
folder1/d1 f1.png
folder1/d1 f2.png
folder1/file.png
deleted -file.png
folder1/folder2
folder1/folder2/d2 f1.png
folder1/folder2/d2 f2.png
folder1/folder2/file.png
deleted -file.png
folder1/folder2/folder 3
folder1/folder2/folder 3/d3 f1.png
folder1/folder2/folder 3/d3 f2.png
folder1/folder2/folder 3/file.png
deleted -file.png`

```
rrmdir('folder1');
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $objects = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
                if (filetype($dir . "/" . $object) == "dir") {

                    echo $dir . "/" . $object . '<br>';
                    rrmdir($dir . "/" . $object);
                } else {
                    // unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
                    echo $dir . "/" . $object . '<br>';
                    if ($object == 'file.png') {
                        echo "deleted  -" . $object . '<br>';
                        unlink($dir . "/" . $object);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        reset($objects);
        // rmdir($dir);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explanation of what you're doing is always valuable.